# CSV::can't convert String into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, csv, import

I would like to import csv file into my database. I am using Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 3.2.13 and the gem 'csv_importer'.

I am going to fetch productname and release_date from csv file

In my controller

```
 def import
        csv_text = File.read('test.csv')
        csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
        csv.each do |row|
            puts row  #getting entire values from csv 
            puts row['productname'] #getting error
 end
```

If I print row/row[0], I am getting entire values from csv file as

productname,release_date

xxx,yyy

in my log.

If I print row['productname'], I am getting error as can't convert String into Integer.

How can I rectify this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are actually expecting the [FasterCSV](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/) API, which does support a signature like `parse(csv_text, :headers => true)`.

In Ruby version 1.9 the `CSV` library in stdlib was replaced with the `FasterCSV` library. Your code looks like it might work straight up in Ruby 1.9+.

If you want to use the `FasterCSV` style API without upgrading to a newer Ruby, you can grab the gem and use it instead of `CSV`:

```
require 'fastercsv'
csv_text = File.read('test.csv')
csv = FasterCSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
csv.each do |row|
  puts row['productname']
end
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-parse:

> `CSV.parse(str_or_readable, fs = nil, rs = nil, &block)`
>
> Parse lines from given string or stream. Return rows as an Array of Arrays.

... so `row` in your case is an `Array`. `Array[]` takes an `Integer` as argument`, not a`String`, which is why you're getting the error.

In other words; `row['anything']` cannot work, but `row[0]` and `row[1]` will give you the values from column 1 and 2 of the row.

Now, in your case, you are actually calling `CSV.parse` like so:

```
CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
```

Looking at the docs, we see that the second argument to `CSV.parse` is the field separator. You're passing `:headers => true` as a field separator. That tells `CSV` to split each row whenever it encounters the string `"headerstrue"` - it doesn't, so it doesn't split each row.

If you remove the second argument to `CSV.parse` you should be closer to what you expect.

Comment: Oh, that's what that meant. Updated my answer with even more documentation reading.